# Linq to XElement Preparation with some condtions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
private XElement GetClinicalClientPrice(int invid)
{
    using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase())
    {
        return new XElement("CLINICALCLIENTPRICE",
                       from ccp in db.TblClinicalClientPrice
                       where ccp.INVENTORY_ID == invid
                       select new XElement("Record",
                        new XElement("ITEM_ID",ccp.ITEM_ID),
                        new XElement("INVENTORY_ID", ccp.INVENTORY_ID),
                        new XElement("ITEM_DESCRIPTION", ccp.ITEM_DESCRIPTION),
                        new XElement("SUPPLIER_CAT", ccp.SUPPLIER_CAT),
                        new XElement("NDC_CODE", ccp.NDC_CODE),
                        new XElement("ITEM_NUMBER", ccp.ITEM_NUMBER),
                        new XElement("UOM", ccp.UOM),
                        new XElement("CONVERSION_FACTOR", ccp.CONVERSION_FACTOR),
                        new XElement("MANUFACTURER", ccp.MANUFACTURER),
                        new XElement("SESSION_ID", ccp.SESSION_ID),
                        new XElement("USERNAME", ccp.USERNAME),
                        new XElement("ENTRY_TIME", ccp.ENTRY_TIME),
                        new XElement("COST", ccp.COST),
                        new XElement("CLIENT_INPUT_ID", ccp.CLIENT_INPUT_ID),
                        new XElement("MHS_ITEM_ID", ccp.MHS_ITEM_ID),
                        new XElement("GUID", ccp.GUID),
                        new XElement("UNIQUE_ID", ccp.UNIQUE_ID),
                        new XElement("SUPPLIER_CAT_MODIFIED", ccp.SUPPLIER_CAT_MODIFIED),
                        new XElement("SIZE", ccp.SIZE),
                        new XElement("STRENGTH", ccp.STRENGTH)
                       ));
    }
}
```

---

I am getting (DateTime) Null value exception when I am inserting above resulted XElement into data base.
My Example is : [stackoverflow.com/a/21163312/3121707](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bttAy.jpg)

[image: My code as follows...]

[image: My XElement structure as follows...]

Comment: The code you've given just *fetched* from the database. If the exception is when you're *inserting* into the database, you should show that code - along with the XML which is causing the problem.

Comment: Please, provide code relevant to your question, and error you have

Comment: Please go through the images .....Thanks in advance!